# Understanding CPU architecture abbreviations

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, intel, amd-processor

I have installed ubuntu on a pc. Now I would like to know its CPU architecture. I have read that uname -a can be used for this so:

```
~$ uname -a
Linux desknode1 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

from this page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

I have deduced that its an AMD cpu. But if  I run:

```
~$ grep --color "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
~$
```

indicating that its an intel quad core. I have also tried to run **lscpu** :

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 23
Stepping:              6
CPU MHz:               2659.954
BogoMIPS:              5320.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

The:
   Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel

indicates an intel CPU. So what cpu is on this machine?

Comment: From the very Wikipedia page you have referenced: "The original specification was created by AMD, and has been implemented by AMD, Intel, VIA, and others". Your conclusion that you're running on an AMD CPU has been a bit hasty.

Answer (score 3):

"uname -a" shows you only for which architecture kernel was compiled. For example, there is no problem with using 32bit kernel (uname) on 64bit cpu (/proc/cpuinfo).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're getting AMD from. x86_64 means you have a 64-bit processor and that it's an x86 processor. This can be either Intel or AMD. Since everything else says Intel, you have Intel.

Comment: Ok so the command to rely on is grep --color "model name" /proc/cpuinfo and not uname -a when it comes to figuring out if its an intel or AMD?

Answer (score 0):

You have a Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6.

Google reveals that you have an Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Extreme CPU X9650 @ 3.00 GHz.

In other word, you have 4-core CPU for an 8-Hyperthreadable CPUs.

http://www.jackcobben.nl/?p=2013